# Locale for Great Britain configuration in Magnolia 5.3.9 EE

Tags: magnolia

We are using Magnolia 5.3.9 Enterprise edition in our project. Developed pages which support multiple languages like en,sv,fr,fi,..etc., We have developed this by configuring the languages entries under,
STK > site definitions > oursite > i18n > locales > en/fr/de/sv/....

[locale configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54pyQ.png)

As our client's requirement (in specific) is, to have the page/s with Great Britain English along the other locales. But English is already configured as 'en' ( and also it is defaultLocale and fallbackLocale). What are the specific entries to configure Great Britian English as locale? Is there any possible way to go?

Thanks in advance,
TMJ

Comment: Does your client want to have just one English locale (just using British English), or does (s)he want to have both English (let's say "international") **and** British locale? In the first case, it is enough to use British English when editing the pages in `en` locale. In the second case, define new `en_GB` locale and set country to `GB`.

Comment: thank you Jozef...I have tried the same it worked.

Comment: Sorry..there is a typo in subject :) version is 5.3.9